# How can I discover and compensate for possible flaws in the method of date storage?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have a list of items which have states within date ranges, and some counts are coming up wrong (technically correct, but wrong in intent).

I'm wondering if there's some examples of the date ranges not matching up closely on the datetimes I'm checking, or if the datetimes I'm querying on happen to fall into holes in the date ranges between rows.

The table looks something like this:

```
table_above
itemid | start                   | stop                    | state
1234   | 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2014-02-01 10:04:00.000 | 1
1234   | 2014-02-01 10:04:00.003 | NULL                    | 2
1111   | 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL                    | 2
```

`itemid 1234` was at `state 1` for about 14 years, then on `Feb 1` it switched to `state 2`, and the `stop = null` means that to this moment, `item 1234` is in `state 2`.

`item 1111` has been in `state 2` since `2000-01-01 00:00:00.000`, and is in `state 2` currently.

There was a tiny period of time when the DB recorded no state at all for `itemid 1234` for the following two datetimes: `'2014-02-01 10:04:00.001'` and `'2014-02-01 10:04:00.002'`

Since my counts aren't coming up quite the way I expected, I'd like to check whether it's because of this issue.

The query I run counts the number of items in a particular state at a particular datetime:

```
select
  count(1)
where
  start < '2014-02-01 12:00:00.000'
  and (stop >= '2014-02-01 12:00:00.000' or stop is null)
  and state = 2
from
  table_above
```

This would return `2` for table_above.  However, the following query would return `1`.

```
select
  count(1)
where
  start < '2014-02-01 10:04:00.001'
  and (stop >= '2014-02-01 10:04:00.001' or stop is null)
  and state = 2
from
  table_above
```

The problem is that in reality, for those tiny period of time, the items associated with those `itemid`s exist, but they're not being counted anywhere.

The query is technically correct, but I need it to represent intention instead.

If they fall into those gaps, I'd like to count them as the state they were in immediately prior to the gaps.

Also, is there any way I can run a query to print all gaps for a particular `itemid`?

Finally, I'm suspicious whether there is any overlap in the date ranges where there shouldn't be, and I'd like a query to discover whether there is any overlap.  At any given time, an item can only be in one state at a time, but I'd like to check whether there are some points where items have multiple states, such as in the example below.

```
table_above
itemid | start                   | stop                    | state
1234   | 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2014-02-01 10:04:00.000 | 1
1234   | 2014-02-01 10:03:59.999 | NULL                    | 2
```

If I ran the query above twice, with `state = 2` or `state = 1` for the time point `'2014-02-01 10:04:00.000'`, both would return a count of `1`, but it is intended that each item have only one state at each point in time, so they should not both return `1`

Comment: TLDR, but why state 2 started before state 1 stopped in the last example?

Comment: The last example was an data recording I'm not sure is occurring, but I'd like to check whether it is.  The real-life event of an item having two states should not be happening, but I don't know whether the DB event like the one shown (at the end) is happening.

Comment: you haven't posted any `insert` nor `update` statements. if the data appear in the database by black (box) magic, then anything is possible.

Comment: As far as `insert` or `update` statements, I'm not responsible for the way the DB is structured, I'm just trying to work with it.  I'm trying to discover and compensate for possible flaws in the method of data storage.I don't know what "black (box) magic" means.  Could you please be more specific, or use less jargon?

Comment: @user38858: It's not about who's responsible for the structure. It's about making it easy for us to give you answers. If you don't post CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements, everybody who wants to answer has to either reverse-engineer your query, or write untested code off the top of their head.

Comment: Conceptually, for state information, `stop` is _derived_ information, as no such info actually exists: really, it's when the next state **starts**.  The fact that there's two "uncovered" values is solely the product of the datatype chosen - if you had one of the others, there would be far more available.  What version of SQL Server?  Ideally you could use `LAG()`/`LEAD()` to construct the "true" `stop` timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer have some useful information, but here are some other thing to consider also:

- If you're using a `datetime` type, then the values are *always* going to be rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007, because that's it's precision.  This is [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).
- Comparing a `datetime` to a string will cast that string to a `datetime`, so actually there is no "tiny period" of unrepresentation.  Consider the following:

  ```
  declare @dt0 datetime, @dt1 datetime, @dt2 datetime, @dt3 datetime
  select @dt0 = '2014-02-01 10:04:00.000',
         @dt1 = '2014-02-01 10:04:00.001',
         @dt2 = '2014-02-01 10:04:00.002',
         @dt3 = '2014-02-01 10:04:00.003'

  if @dt0 = @dt1 print 'True' else print 'False'
  if @dt2 = @dt3 print 'True' else print 'False'
  ```

  Both tests print `True` because of the rounding happening with `datetime`.  If you really need more precise values, consider using `datetime2` instead.
- Your logic is a bit off for the range comparison.  Usually, the start of the range is inclusive while the end of the range is exclusive. You have this reversed.

  Instead of:

  ```
  start < '2014-02-01 12:00:00.000'
  and (stop >= '2014-02-01 12:00:00.000' or stop is null)
  ```

  It should be:

  ```
  start <= '2014-02-01 12:00:00.000'
  and (stop > '2014-02-01 12:00:00.000' or stop is null)
  ```

Comment: No, which side of the range was inclusive was correct, he's doing an exclusion range.  That is, he actually has two ranges here (one over `start`, the other over `stop`), with the other bound over the max/min value.  If any pair of rows has matching `start`/`stop` values, your version would include both.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - No, mine is also excluding the overlapping value.  The point is, usually the start value is within the range, while the stop value belongs to the next range.  Example, for the ranges "1:00 to 2:00", "2:00 to 3:00" - the value 1:00 is in the first range, while 2:00 is only in the second range, and 3:00 is in not in either.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like a query to discover whether there is any overlap. At any given time, an item can only be in one state at a time, but I'd like to check whether there are some points where items have multiple states

You could try something like the following to capture when the start/stop date of a status lands between the start and stop date of another status:

```
Select A.itemid
From table_above A
    Join table_above B
    On A.itemid = B.itemid
Where B.start Between A.start And A.stop
       Or B.stop Between A.start And A.stop
```

Comment: What if B.start was *not* between A.start and A.stop, but B.stop *was*?

Comment: @MikeSherrilCatRecall Edited for the above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, is there any way I can run a query to print all gaps for a
>   particular itemid?

In SQL Server 2012, you can do this pretty easily with the lag() analytic function. (In earlier versions, use subqueries.)

```
select *
from (select itemid, start, stop, state, 
             lag(stop) over (partition by itemid order by start) prev_stop
      from table_above) x
where start <> prev_stop;
```

That query will give you all the rows where the value for "start" is different from the value for the previous "stop". You can add "itemid" to the WHERE clause if you need to check for a single itemid, and you can subtract "prev_stop" from "start" if you want to consider values within, say 500msec as being equal.

> If they fall into those gaps, I'd like to count them as the state they
>   were in immediately prior to the gaps.

I think that's *almost* the same as saying, "When there's a gap, change the stop time to equal the following start time." If I'm right about that, then I think this query gives you a good working table.

```
select itemid,
       start,
       case when datediff(ms, next_start, stop) <= 500 then next_start
            else stop
       end as stop,
       state
from
  (select *, lead(start) over (partition by itemid order by start) next_start
  from table_above) x;
```

I'd probably wrap that in a CREATE VIEW statement, and base your counts on it instead of the base tables.